# What is the blessing on dark chocolate?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

What do poskim say the bracha is for dark chocolate that has more than 50% cacao in it as the package claims (being that the majority ingredient is cacao)?

(I've seen an opinion who says (Vzot Habracha p. 103 in the name of R' Elyashiv) that we make a shehakol on chocolate even though it warrants a ha'eitz, because there are other ingredients mixed in (they add in parenthesis that there were other reasons for the psak but do not mention the factors). My case would seem to be an exception to that because it is rov cacao.)

Comment: I'm really curious to know what R Elyashiv's actual view is. According to the questioner in Shevet Halevi 7.27.2, R' Elyashiv holds it is he'eitz (and doesn't mention any qualifications for the amount or type ingredients).

Comment: An article from R' Kaganoff about what bracha to make on chocolate: http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=6500. According to R' Kaganoff cocoa butter should be a shehakol. This complicates matters, because even if there's >50% cacao in the bar, there may not be >50% cacao solids but rather mostly cocoa butter.

Answer (score 8):

The opinion that you quote is most likely that of R' Shlomo Zalman Aurbach, and can be found in [Minchas Shlomo 1:91 beis](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15097&st=&pgnum=249). In truth, he says this as a post facto justification of the normative practice to make *shehakol* on chocolate even though he believes the *beracha* should have been *ha'eitz*.

However, his point is not merely that it is a minority ingredient - his point is that since it is only eaten through being mixed with other ingredients such that it is usually a minority ingredient, and it isn't really edible in its pure form, then it has lost its חשיבות, its significance, and even when it is a majority ingredient it has lost its significance and gets a *shehakol*. If you eat pure cocoa with sugar and the majority is cocoa, however, he concludes that you should, indeed, make a *ha'eitz*.

Comment: +1 good thing I read your link. I was wondering if his svara would help be mivatel the raw fish in sushi, but he focuses on the fact that cocoa gets ground up.

Comment: @user6591 I was about to ask about eating plain Hershey's cocoa as it is in the "can", but your comment answered my question, MOSTLY. The one part it doesn't answer falls within the area of "what do most people do?" Generally, if most people don't eat a fruit / veg raw, you make *shehakol* on it. As most don't eat raw chocolate, therefore, shouldn't you make *shehakol* too if you ate baker's chocolate?

Comment: @DanF you started with raw chocolate and then went to baker's chocolate.  If you meant raw chocolate, see Shulchan Aruch Orech Chayim 203:7 and Mogen Avrohom 202:18, which should answer your question. If you meant baker's chocolate, then (assuming I understand what baker's chocolate is) that would be included in what RSZ was saying, and you would indeed make _shehakol_.

Comment: @DanF plain bakers chocolate, according to the logic in that tshuva would seemingly not get a bracha at all! He compares it to the olive oil of the gemara. That's what it seems like he's saying, although he is only discussing chocolate mixed with sugar.

Comment: http://www.srugim.co.il/137050-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9A-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93-%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%A5

Comment: Reviving this discussion: the SA in siman 203 states that a in mixture of spices and sugar, the spices are עיקר, and you make the ברכה that is the usual bracha for spices, not on the sugar. The MB #13 says that this is even if the mixture is mostly sugar. Following this logic, even for regular chocolate, and even milk chocolate (!) the bracha should be העץ, since most cacao is grown to be made into edible chocolate, and the other ingredients (sugar, milk) are טפל. This would follow the first opinion quoted by the Rama in 202:7.

Answer (score 1):

I Heard from (רבי יחזקא-ל ראטה (קארלסבורג רב  (Rabbi Y. Roth Karelsburger Rav), That the reason why Chocolate is שהכל (shehakol) is because originally Chocolate was only consumed as a drink, therefore it got the ברכה (Bracha) of שהכל (shehakol), like all fruit juices ( Besides grape juice ), and even though the fact has changed over the years, that we eat chocolate as a food the ברכה (Bracha) isn't changed.

But in the case that the chocolate has some העץ (ha'eitz) on it ( like Viennese crunch etc. ) the ברכה (Bracha) is העץ (ha'eitz).

According to that in your case no matter the % of cacao the ברכה (bracha) should be שהכל (shehakol).

Comment: "But in the case that the chocolate has some העץ (ha'eitz) on it ( like Viennese crunch etc. ) the ברכה (Bracha) is העץ (ha'eitz)." - The chocolate is *ikkar* and the nuts are *tafel*, in this case. Why would this warrant saying *ha'etz*? (also, if the nuts are peanuts, at least it would be *adamah*, anyway.)

Comment: Because originally the ברכה should've been העץ it is just שהכל because it wasn't eaten only as a drink, However in a case that you have anything else העץ you can re-institute the ברכה it should've gotten to begin with.

Comment: Why doesn't the bracha change now that usage has changed?

Comment: Cause once we are "Kovea" a ברכה on a food we don't change it according to it's current use.

Comment: Your last comment seems to contradict the 2nd one, above. First, you said that it should have been העץ but b/c it was used mainly as a drink, it became שהכל. So it seems that originally it WAS changed b/c of its usage. What have I missed in the explanation?

Comment: By change I meant from it's originally instituted ברכה, and שהכל was the ברכה originally instituted to chocolate b/c the above stated reason.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer I don't know what it means to "Kovea" a ברכה on a food. The first person who makes a Beracha on a food decides? AFAICT there is no such concept in Judaism.

Comment: When chocolate was first brought to the areas populated with Jews so the issue of which bracha (ברכה) to make on it was brought up that's when the rabbis were kovea a bracha (ברכה) for it.