# "Halachikly Complicated" Foods (Safek Bracha)

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, purim, safek

Over the Shabbos meal we discussed the idea of sending "Halachikly Complicated" Mishloach Manos. "Halachikly Complicated" meaning foods that cannot be eaten because we have a safek what their bracha is, and therefore cannot be eaten (except for during a meal in which you made hamotzie OR making a bracha on a number of other foods that you otherwise would not eat)

What are examples of such foods?

Comment: It would be good if you could justify in the question that such a rule exists: that one can't eat something "we" don't know the _b'racha_ for. I'd think that (although one can't eat something **he** doesn't know the _b'racha_ for) if there's something "we" don't know the _b'racha_ for then one can eat it with a _b'racha_ encompassing both possibilities in terms of generality.

Comment: @mbloch Some people like making "themed" mishloach manos (breakfast, green, us mail, ect....) It would be a "theme" mishloach manos, no different from other themes, but enjoyable for those who like "cute halacha ideas"

Comment: @msh210 "uneatable" is retorical, though it is probably the wrong word. I'll change it to "Halachikly Complicated".

Comment: @msh210 Too broad?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/959 cc @DoubleAA

Answer (score 2):

I understand the concept now. A few ideas

- soufganyot - there is a doubt whether they are mezonot or hamotzi. Because it is fried challah-dough, there is a machloket whether the frying removes the hamotzi. Some are machmir not to eat without hamotzi
- chocolate-covered raisins or nuts - until you open/eat one, you don't know what bracha - and even then it depends if you like the chocolate or raisin more
- chocolate - R Shlomo Zalman Auerbach [held](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shehakol#cite_note-5) it is haeitz although most/all say sheakol

Comment: Similarly Orange Juice, Chazon Ish felt was ha'eitz.

Comment: if raisin or nut is covered in chocolate then there is no safek the bracha would be shehakol. Similarly, a apple pie would be mezonos and not haeitz because the surrounding material is mezonos.

Comment: @Dude no what I wrote is correct. A chocolate covered nut is haeitz if you prefer the nut, sheakol if you prefer the chocolate. Mezonot is different as it takes priority in most cases, see eg http://halachipedia.com/documents/5772/10.pdf

Comment: @mbloch Even if you prefer the chocolate it might be haeitz http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/59669/759

Comment: @DoubleAA yes this is my third point in the answer above - on this I heard a cute story. Apparently when a grandkid asked him what bracha to say on a chocolate he just got, RSZA answered "ask your grandmother" because even he wasn't sure it was really *l'maase*

Comment: Pretty sure the Shulchan Aruch Harav holds that it is haeitz, although the practice of his chasidim was to make shehakol(?)

Answer (score 0):

Granola - the oats are a safek mezonos/haadama
Rice

Puffed Wheat - there is a shita that holds that since wheat is one of the & species, one would have to make a "Al Hoadama" Afterbracha (similar to Al HaPeiros made on grapes, figs, dates, olives, pomegranete). Since in practice we dont make this bracha at all, such a food would be "unedible" except for during a meal of bread.

Comment: So too on, eg. meat, there is a Machloket if Borei Nefashot ends with a Chatima BeShem or not, so meat and cheese and juice should only be eaten in a bread meal.

Comment: @DoubleAA There are people who do not eat wheat outside of a meal because of this machlokes, whereas Borei nefashos seems to have an established psak.

Comment: Established? I know people alive today who say a Chatima BeShem and some who don't. Why is that any different from the other examples?